# в c# при попытке совершить запрос http ошибка

Tags: c#, http

при попытке сделать запрос к серверу (любому)
Необработанное исключение типа "System.Net.WebException" в System.dll
Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку: (404) Не найден
вчера сделал программу к доступу api вк
вчера всё рвботало отлично , сегодня не работает ничего , и это не с вк связано.
может что то блокирует процесу vshost.exe делать выход в интернет. 
помогите реально проблема. спасибо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 404 - значит что ваш код достучался до сервера. и сервер ответил "не найден". Вы пытаетесь запросить url, который, с точки зрения сервера, больше не существует. Какой именно - из скриншота непонятно.

Comment: ты понимаешь что любой сервер не отвечает!!!

Comment: я даже stackoverflow пробывал , ничего

Comment: >> вчера всё рвботало отлично<< вспомните тот день, убедитесь что не настраивали проксей, и сетевых экранов, посмотрите соединение и убедитесь что с настройками протокола для вашего соединения всё в порядке. Так же, убедитесь что в вашей сети не работает никаких VPN-ов.